# Should I place this jquery inside an angular controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, controller, radio-button

In a html table I have a list of rows that are constructed using ng-repeat. Inside those rows I have a radio button that uses jquery to change the style. The style is applied by using this jquery...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.i-checks').iCheck({
checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
});
});
</script>
```

When I place this code in the page, the radio button styling does not work. However, if I place the code in the table row - it does work...

```
<div ng-controller="supplierController" class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 m-t-m">
<div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
        <h5>Price results </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Vendor</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="supplier in suppliers.prices">
                <td>{{ supplier.supplier_name }}</td>
                <td>£{{ supplier.price }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio i-checks"><label> <input
type="radio"  name="a"> <i>this</i></label>
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
                });
            });
        </script>

</div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works - but obviously its a terrible idea, as the jquery is rendered for EVERY row. So my question is, where is the best place to put this code, so that it also works? Should I put it into the controller?

Apologies if I am not being clear, I'm new to Angular.

Many thanks

Comment: If it interacts with the dom (in this case, that is true) it should be in a directive. The only exceptions i've seen thus far are when creating a service to handle dialogs or alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directive just for the plugin part is really quite easy to throw together

```
angular.module('YourApp').directive('iChecks', function () {    
    return {
        restrict: 'C', // for class in markup
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // element is jQuery object (see note below)
            element.iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Will require that you include jQuery.js *before* angular.js in page. When you do that `angular.element` uses the full jQuery library.

Next steps would be to add behaviors. Note that any events that modify the scope will need to use `scope.$apply()` in order to tell angular to run a digest cycle

Answer (score 0):

As you have said correctly, what you are doing is a terrible idea. And as Kevin has already said in a comment, you should be creating a directive.

I created a small gist to enable to apply arbitrary JQuery plugins.

https://gist.github.com/ameyms/4f3a5d6a8d329609d44e

> PS: I haven't tested it out, so don't know if it works!

Comment: Just a suggestion, add a usage view to the gist.